# Facebook Auth Dialog display page

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0

Is it not possible to `display` the Auth Dialog as `page` any longer?

It used to work, but now I can't seem to get it to work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you publish the link you used to call to display the Auth Dialog as a windows? (Hide your App ID)

Comment: You don't need to hide the app ID. That value is public. Just don't share your app secret.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the authentication screen as a full page (rather than a popup window), simply redirect your users to the following URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<app_id>&redirect_uri=<app_url>&scope=email
```

- You can find your `app_id` at: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
- You can read all about Facebook auth at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/